# Laravel 8 - Payumoney integration success page issue

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway, payumoney

Let me clear the whole scenario here

From **PayuFormData()** i am sending user cart details to payumoney form.

From **Returnpay()** i am just returning view page (**SURL** which we given in payumoney form).

My payment is being success, also showing in payumoney dashboard.

The problem is, **I want to show success message and run some insert queries on pay2 page** but it showing this(see image i attached) on **pay2 page**

[image]

Controller:-

```
public function PayuFormData()
{
   $frmdata = DB::table('carts')->where('email',Session::get('email'))->get();
   return view('/pay1')->with('frmdata',$frmdata);
}

public function Returnpay()
{
  return view('/pay2');
}
```

Routes:-

```
 Route::get('/pay1', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@PayuFormData');
 Route::get('/pay2', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@Returnpay');
```

Pay2 Blade View:-

```
@include('header')

<?php

$status=$_POST["status"];
$firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
$amount=$_POST["amount"];
$txnid=$_POST["txnid"];
$posted_hash=$_POST["hash"];
$key=$_POST["key"];
$productinfo=$_POST["productinfo"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$salt="jFdrP6QzU7";
$udf1=$_POST["udf1"];
$udf2=$_POST["udf2"];
$udf3=$_POST["udf3"];
$udf4=$_POST["udf4"];
$udf5=$_POST["udf5"];

// Salt should be same Post Request 

If (isset($_POST["additionalCharges"])) {
       $additionalCharges=$_POST["additionalCharges"];
        $retHashSeq = $additionalCharges.'|'.$salt.'|'.$status.'|||||||||||'.$email.'|'.$firstname.'|'.$productinfo.'|'.$amount.'|'.$txnid.'|'.$key;
  } else {
        $retHashSeq = $salt.'|'.$status.'||||||'.$udf5.'|'.$udf4.'|'.$udf3.'|'.$udf2.'|'.$udf1.'|'.$email.'|'.$firstname.'|'.$productinfo.'|'.$amount.'|'.$txnid.'|'.$key;
         }
     $hash = hash("sha512", $retHashSeq);
       if ($hash != $posted_hash) {
         echo "Invalid Transaction. Please try again";
       } else {

         echo "Payment successful";
         // and some insert queries
       }
?>  

@include('footer')
```

Comment: Shouldn't `Route::get('/pay2', ...);` be  `Route::post('/pay2', ...);` since it seems you do a POST request ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Clément Baconnier

Changed Route to **POST** and **add this code** in C:\xampp\htdocs\larastore\app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    protected $except = [
        'MyPageUrl',
    ];
}
```